# running two exe files with a single batch file in python

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file

I wanted to run two programs using a single batch file in python.

The code below does this, but I want that, when the first program has finished executing the second program will stop running and the batch file will close.

```
@ECHO off
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\Googletalk
start C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\YahooMessenger
```

Comment: Do you have any logic you are currently using for this task to [edit] and add to your question?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done in batch without some third-party utilities that may or may not exist. I'm fairly certain it can be done in Powershell, however - would such a solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
start "my_yahoo" /D "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\" "YahooMessenger"
start /WAIT "my_gtalk" /D "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Softwares\" "Googletalk"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('tasklist /nh /fo csv /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq my_yahoo"') do taskkill /PID %%i /F >NUL 2>&1
endlocal
exit/B
```