# Deal with dollar sign $ when concatenating columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to combine 3 columns with dollar signs,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["$car"], "b": ["$food"],"c":[np.nan]})
```

[image: sample data]

```
df['combine'] = df['a'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['b'].fillna('') + ' ' + df['c'].fillna('')
```

my code give me italic result 
[image: result]

my expected result is 
[image]

I knew that's an interpretation issue in jupyter notebook/python, please advise on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being caused because of the MathJax rendering it.

When you launch the ipython notebook, run it without mathjax using

`ipython notebook --no-mathjax`

Comment: can you please advise how to configure it in Jupyter Notebook, I'm currently using this.

Comment: Execute `jupyter notebook --no-mathjax`

Comment: if I want to schedule the .py script to run in Task Scheduler, how to configure 'jupyter notebook --no-mathjax' into the python.exe while launching. reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727232/scheduling-a-py-file-on-task-scheduler-in-windows-10