# Python: How to Relaunch a Python Daemon Process During Specific Time Intervals?

Tags: python, powershell, process, schedule, relaunch

I just want to run a python process that is being executed remotely from a task machine to run during certain hours of the days. Is there a way to do this from within the Python script itself on Windows?

I want to specify from within the Python Script a list of time intervals:

```
WindowTimes: [(03:00, 05:00), (14:00, 16:00)]
```

The python script (which is basically a giant while loop) should read this list, and only run during those time intervals, so it should exit at 05:00 and then start back up again at 14:00.

The python script is sending a request to and receiving responses from an SFTP site. The Python script is being called remotely via kdb using a powershell script.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually you would use a scheduler to execute the python script. It can start itself if it is not running and won´'t neeed to be started when it runs.

Comment: [SO about win10 shedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727232/scheduling-a-py-file-on-task-scheduler-in-windows-10)