# How to have python code get data from a website then update it on another website?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to have some python code use selenium or bs4 to check a website hourly for updates and the get that information and put it on a website in whatever way I want to format it. I would like to know what's the best way to connect these two together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably set up a cron job ([scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727232/scheduling-a-py-file-on-task-scheduler-in-windows-10) on windows) to run hourly to run your script to scrape the website you're getting data from. The logic in your script will depend on the website you're entering data into, but broadly speaking I would scrape the data, process it, then either send a POST request to the website or update the data source (a db, file, whatever) directly.