# How to set this code to open at specific times of the day?

Tags: python

SO basically how do i do to set this to run at a specific time of the day ?

```
import winsound
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

def timer (reminder,seconds):
    notificator=ToastNotifier()
    notificator=ToastNotifier("Reminder",f"""Alarm will go off in (seconds) Seconds.""",duration=20
    notificator.show_toast(f"Reminder",reminder,duration=20)

    #alarm
    frequency=2500
    duration=1000
    winsound.Beep(frequency,duration)

if __name__=="__main__":
    words=input("What shall i be reminded of: ")
    sec=int(input("Enter seconds: "))
    timer(words,sec)
```

Could this be ? as i tried to write it but doesn t seem to work

```
import time
local_time = float(input())
local_time = local_time * 60
time.sleep(local_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities from the top of my head:

- [Linux] Use cron job https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
- [Any OS] Use scheduler https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- [Windows] [Scheduling a .py file on Task Scheduler in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727232/scheduling-a-py-file-on-task-scheduler-in-windows-10)